# How to redirect to a custom url scheme?

Tags: php, kohana

I have the following code:

```
$uri = 'iosapp://test';
header('Location: '.$uri);
```

(a custom url scheme)

for some reason, PHP (kohana) is not redirecting to that url properly.

What should I be doing differently?

Comment: what is it redirecting to? My guess is it would resolve to http://someurl.comiosapp://test. You're providing a relative URL.

Answer (score 1):

Try using

```
$uri = 'iosapp://test';
HTTP::redirect($uri);
```

http://kohanaframework.org/3.3/guide-api/HTTP#redirect